# Section-wise bibliography using beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

Is there any way to make section-wise references in the beamer similar to the case of chapter-wise references in the thesis?

Comment: You might be interested in the approaches presented in the comments and answers to [How do I add a separate bibtex bibliography in beamer to each lecture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302752/134144)

Comment: I have seen this, but it is not helping me. I want more than 1 frame at different places in a single presentation.

Comment: With multiple `\printbibliography[section=<nr>]` commands with `<nr>` being the number of the corresponding ref section, you can get multiple frames with bibliographies for individual sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `\newrefsection` to separate the sections from each other and multiple `\printbibliography[section=...]` commands:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}


\section{first} \newrefsection
\begin{frame}{first frame of section 1}
Whatever text in the first section
\cite{westfahl:space}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography of section 1}
\printbibliography[section=1]
\end{frame}

\section{second} \newrefsection
\begin{frame}{first frame of section 2}
Whatever text in the first section
\cite{aksin}
\cite{doody}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography of section 2}
\printbibliography[section=2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I also do this using 2 different bib files?  bib file per section?

Comment: So, I have incorporated your code with the one I need. It is successfully running. I have used the theme of Warsaw. And in that theme, all section headings show up at the top. After including your code, Bibliography is also showing as a heading at the top(multiple times). Is there any way to remove it from showing up at the top? The rest is fine.

Comment: As the answers to [How to delete the word 'References' from the navigation bar in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436539/134144) suggest, adding the `heading=none` option to `\printbibliography` command helps.

Comment: It works. Happy now.